# Why the mapStateToProps returns "undefined" in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Why the function **mapStateToProps** returns "undefined" or empty object in React/Redux.

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux";

export const ArticleComponent = ({props}) => (
<div>
    <h1>Hello {console.log(props)}</h1>
</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    text: '11111'
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticleComponent);
```

Comment: How do you accessing the `text` in `ArticleComponent` component?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, hmm, like this this.props.text

Comment: Remove the word `export` at `export class ArticleComponent ...` and add `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticleComponent);`

Comment: @N.Safi changed, look at the code, again undefined :(

Comment: `export const ArticleComponent = ({props}) => (` remove `export`

Comment: @N.Safi, './components/ArticleComponents' does not contain an export named 'ArticleComponent'.

Answer (score 1):

You made multiple mistakes in your code :

---

- You export your initial component AND you make a default export to the connected component.

Remove the export on the initial component and import your default export with :

```
import ArticleComponent from "./ArticleComponent" // No curly braces{ } to import the default;
```

---

- You're accessing `props.props` (which is undefined) by doing `const ArticleComponent = ({props}) =>`

Remove curly braces to access all `props` passed to this component : `const ArticleComponent = (props) =>`(or use curly braces to get only the `{text}` prop)

---

- You log the props in console (this is not an error but I don't think this is intentional)

Display the state like this :  `<h1>Hello {props.text}</h1>`

---

Here's the full code :

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux";

const ArticleComponent = ({text}) => ( // or (props)
<div>
    <h1>Hello {text}</h1> // or {props.text}
</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    text: '11111'
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticleComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the props to be received properly you need to use the connected instance of the component. Import it as a `default import` since connected component is the `default export`.

```
import ArticleComponent from 'path/to/ArticleComponent'
```

Comment: this file is called ArticleComponent.js. All in this file. Changed, still "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you want to extract props from props.

Instead of

```
export const ArticleComponent = ({props})
```

Write

```
const ArticleComponent = (props)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a `const` like this it will never work. And why are you returning a text value (is this just to test it)?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class ArticleComponent extends Component {
render() {
const {text} = this.props
return (
<div>
    <h1>Hello {console.log(text)}</h1>
</div>
)
}
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    text: '11111'
  }
};

ArticleComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(ArticleComponent);

export default  ArticleComponent;
```

Comment: "you can't use a const like this it will never work" This is wrong, simple functions (and arrow functions) can be used in React to create a stateless (or functional) component see the [official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: That is not what I said....as per the official docs you are using a function....not a `const`.....also with `mapStateToProps` it is doing exactly what is says....it can't be stateless

Comment: "The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared." By trying to wrap "connect" in the original code that is exactly what is happening

Comment: Connect doesn't reassign the enhanced component, it returns a new one, the OP issue is about export confusion and props access.

Comment: I made a codepen showing that if you wanna take a look https://codepen.io/Dyo/pen/WyWpqp